# Merge syntax, parentheses when using subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, sql-merge

According to the official [Merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html) syntax, parentheses are not needed with a subquery in the `USING` clause. Yet the examples always have them and if you try it without you get an error message. Is this an error in the specification?

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
   USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 80) S
   ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
     DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000);
```

Comment: Parentheses aren't needed if you reference only a table name in your USING clause.  If you need to use a derived table you'll need to use parentheses like normal.  You can think of the USING clause like a FROM clause in this instance.  So if you Select * from Table you don't need the parentheses but if you use a derived table (select column from table where column = 'x') then you do.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, a **subquery** itself means *something enclosed into parentheses*. Did you ever see a subquery which "stands alone"? I did not.

```
select whatever 
from (select blabla from dual)     --> subquery, in parentheses
```

or

```
select (select dummy from dual)   --> parentheses again
from ...
```

etc.

Why would `MERGE` make an exception?

---

Oracle documentation itself doesn't explicitly mention parentheses, except for *scalar subqueries*. Though, "general rules" (returned by Google search) say "a subquery must be enclosed in the parentheses". I'd just accept it *as is*, if I were you.

Comment: I think it is more about formal part of the documentation text and exact notation used in it. `SELECT` definition starts with [```subquery [for_update_clause]```](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html) and it definitely does not require to be parenthesized. The only way to figure out where do you need to put parentheses being the first man in the Universe and having only the documentation by hand is to look at examples (which are more like possible ways, not exact ways). Maybe they've missed this little part in their great documentation.

Comment: 'Did you ever see a subquery which "stands alone"?' Every select starts with 
 a subquery: [SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html)

Comment: So, `select * from dual` is, actually, a *subquery*? Is that what you are saying, @Roland?

Comment: Yes, according to the official Oracle syntax.

Comment: If you say so, @Roland. I'm not that convinced, though. Documentation says "A query is an operation that retrieves data from one or more tables or views. In this reference, a top-level SELECT statement is called a query, and a query nested within another SQL statement is called a subquery. " Therefore, they aren't synonymous (which is what you, I believe, think).

Comment: Semantically you are right. But this topic is about syntax(2nd word in the title). Syntactically every query starts with a subquery.

Comment: Aha, now I understand what you are trying to say, @Roland. OK.